# what is causing this program to not execute reliably

Tags: c

I have recently made a program that is supposed to take two environment variables, insert them into a string, then send the string to popen, and it works fine most of the time, but for some reason it will randomly not execute every so often, so I was just wondering if anyone saw any possible errors or mistakes that I am making?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

   char *output;
   char *ccode;
   char *command;
   char *log;

   command = malloc(1024);
   log = malloc(1024);
   const char *parg = getenv("MCEXEC_ARGS");
   const char *pname = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");

   if(strcmp(parg,"")==0) {
       output = "Usage: /staff <message>";
       printf( "%s\n", output );
       return 0;
   }

   freopen("/dev/null","w",stdout);

   if (argv[1] == NULL) {
       snprintf(command, 1024,
                "/home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py 'sendmsgtogroup staff §f(§bSTAFF§f) <%s§f> %s'",
                pname, parg);
       snprintf(log, 1024,
                "/home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py 'savetolog info staffmsg: <%s> %s'",
                pname, parg);
   }
   else if (strcmp(argv[1],"me")==0) {
       snprintf(command, 1024,
                "/home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py 'sendmsgtogroup staff §f(§bSTAFF§f) * %s§f %s'",
                pname, parg);
       snprintf(log, 1024,
                "/home/minecraft/remoteclient01a.py 'savetolog info staffmsg: * %s %s'",
                pname, parg);
   }

   popen(command, "w");
   popen(log, "w");

   free(command);
   free(log);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you include any details about what happens and what precludes the program not executing correctly?

Comment: "but for some reason it will randomly not execute every so often" - in what way does it 'not execute'?

Comment: You're not handling any error code from your system calls so how can you even expect to debug that.

Comment: Could you please do us a favor and exclude all the irrelevant details from the code? (Checking the command line arguments is one of them.)

Comment: Possible NULL pointer being passed to `strcmp()`, if `"MCEXEC_ARGS"` is not an environment variable.

Comment: when the program does not execute, it just does not return any input then exits out (not stdout of course since that is being sent to null), this program is called by another process from an ingame environment so for instance someone would do /something blabla in game, which would set MCEXEC_ARGS to blabla, MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME to playername and then execute the program which could be something like /home/bla/something (something being the program) pretty much like a symlink to the program from ingame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ...

- You're not checking that `malloc()` succeeds.
- You're not handling that the environment variables might not exist.
- You're calling `strcmp()` on a pointer that might be NULL; which might kill your program right there.
- You're not checking that the file open succeeds.
- You have weird § characters in the commands strings, not sure if those are intended.
- You're not checking if `popen()` succeeds.
- I don't think your usage of `popen()` makes sense; you're not using the pipes once opened.

Comment: Add to that: `popen` runs the command via a shell, so there's no need to do your own environment variable expansion. Just use `$FOO`...

Comment: Also not checking `snprintf` for string overflow…